# Formula about change of base

Tags: vector-spaces, riemannian-geometry, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be a $n$-dim vector space, $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ is a positive orthonormal basis, $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is an arbitrary  positive basis, how to show 
$$
v_1\wedge \cdots\wedge v_n =\sqrt{det(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle)}\ e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_n
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n={\rm det}\ [v_1\cdots v_n]\ e_1\wedge\cdots \wedge e_n $$

If $V=[v_1\cdots v_n]$, then $$ {\rm det}\ V =\sqrt{{\rm det}\ V^TV} $$ Here $V^TV$ has entry $(v_i,v_j)$ so that we complete the proof

Comment: what is ${\rm det}\ [v_1\cdots v_n]$ ? Why $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n={\rm det}\ [v_1\cdots v_n]\ e_1\wedge\cdots \wedge e_n$ ?

Comment: ${\rm det}\ [v_1\cdots v_n]$ is determinant of a matrix $[v_1\cdots v_n]$ And recall the definition of determinant Wedge product $v_1\wedge\cdots \wedge v_n$ satisfies the definition of determinant

Comment: I understand, Thanks very much.